# Module as a functor

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, category-theory, modules, functors

A left $R$-module is said to be a covariant functor from the category with one object $R$ to the category of abelian groups. Is this $R$ considered as a ring or as or as a left $R$ module? I am only able to interpret it as the latter since a module is given by a homomorphism from $R$ to $End(M)$, where $M$ is an abelian group. And $R$ as a ring is isomorphic to $End(R)$ where $R$ is viewed as a left module. But in the texts it's not stated that they consider that single object to be a module, so I assume I'm wrong.

Comment: It should be an $\text{Ab}$-enriched functor from the $\text{Ab}$-enriched category with one object and endomorphism ring $R$; you can, if you like, think of the object as $R$ itself, as a *right* $R$-module.

Comment: Maybe the first pages of Borceux "Handbook of categorical algebra II" can be of assistance. The category of modules can be seen as the category of *additive* functors between $R$ - seen as one object additive category - and the additive category $\operatorname{Ab}$ (= what Qiaochu said). Arrows in this category are natural transformations, and they correspond to module morphisms.